# How to export 2d svg image from blender

Tags: blender

I found free style SVG exporter to export SVG image from blender, but that will gives me 3D SVG image.

I want to export 2D view image with top view of camera, can any one know how we can do this in blender?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found on Video on Youtube [2D SVG from 3D object in Blender](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OHqabjzrp8). May be Help you.

Its works using below steps.

```
1. Press 7 for top ortho 
2. Press ctrl+alt+0 to top camera persp.
3. Now check both checkbox on bottom right "Free Style", and "Free Style SVG Export"
4. Change path and press F12 or goto Render>Render Image.
```